# MySQL migrate data from a table with a set field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a set column that contains 2 languages and another column on this table containing an order.

Is it possible migrate my table and to create a record in a new table for each set item with a MySQL query?

Directly migrating records works with records that have a set column without a language combination. But if a record would contain a set of languages I am left with one record with an empty column for language. I would preferably want 2 new records inserted into my fresh table.

One for each language in the set.

```
INSERT INTO newtable (
    newtable.oldtable_id, 
    newtable.language, 
    newtable.order
)
SELECT oldtable.id, oldtable.languages, oldtable.order
FROM oldtable
WHERE oldtable.order IS NOT NULL;
```

I doubt it is possible but I would still like to know if somebody might have a workaround for this since I need to migrate the data somehow.

Comment: Your question  is not clear to me   Try adding an sample data ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper table with one field that lists all languages that can be in the set column. The table can be a temporary one that you drop after the migration. Then create an `insert ... select ...` statement in which you join the source table on the helper table using MySQL's [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (
newtable.oldtable_id, 
newtable.language, 
newtable.order
)
SELECT oldtable.id, helpertable.language, oldtable.order
FROM oldtable inner join helpertable ON find_in_set(helpertable.language, oldtable.languages)>0;
```